# How to securely register non-routing clicks on page via AJAX/update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, security, ruby-on-rails-4, protect-from-forgery

I want to register various clicks on a webpage, e.g. toggle visibility of elements.

The clicks come from users not logged in.

I have an `Impression` model with an `actions` attribute that stores key-value pairs of actions made on a certain page.

On a click event I'm updating a record with this function:

```
function sendAjax(id, data) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "PATCH",
      url: '/impressions/update',
      data: {'impression_id' : id, 'actions' : data},
      success: function(events){
      }
   });  
}
```

But I'm realizing that this is not secure at all, the user could theoretically update whatever record she wants.

How could I do this more securely, can I take advantage of Rails' `protect_from_forgery` in any way with my use case?

Comment: My initial thought was adding an additional hash value that you would generate with a secret token only you posses and the action you want to protect, and then verify it before saving the impression, but still, there is no way to prevent the user from doing a request sending that hash as well, effectively modifying any other record, but at least you would protect yourself from random records coming in.

Comment: You're on to something. What I *could* do is to encrypt the ID of the record I'm updating such that it isn't a plain replacable number and then decrypting it upon updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a necessary feature. Maybe you think too much :)

Even in Google Analytic you can't stop a visitor from manipulating his action, theoretically. One can push any events he want just in console.

Also it's not necessary for analytic tool to be 100% secure and precise. There must be noises, you can ease them but can't really avoid them, or avoid them in a reasonable cost.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the `Impression` from impressions belongs to the `current_user`.

Example:

```
def update
  @impression = current_user.impressions.find(params[:impression_id])
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I'm registering clicks for all visitors, including not logged in... :/

Comment: Everybody can, any given visitor to the webpage. An `Impression` record is created for each page request and then I want to register actions taken on that page that don't include redirection or rendering of new template. And these actions get saved in the `actions` attribute as a `Hash` on the earlier created `Impression` record.